# It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK in React App & Invalid API key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have created a React app and use **firestore** on it. I've tried to integrate **firebase authentication** to my app for authorizing logins, according to this document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

**firebase.js :**

```js
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ***,
  authDomain: ***,
  projectId: ***,
  storageBucket: ***,
  messagingSenderId: ***,
  appId: ***,
  measurementId: ***,
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

And I have a context file named **AuthContext.js** :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import { authentication } from "./firestore";

export const AuthContext = createContext();
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    authentication.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And this is **App.js** :

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "./pages/Routes/Nav";
import Footer from "./pages/Routes/Footer";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Search from "./pages/Search";
import Detail from "./pages/Detail";
import User from "./pages/User";
import LoginSignup from "./pages/LoginSignup";
import { AuthProvider } from "./utility/AuthContext";

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact>
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/search">
              <Search />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/detail/:id">
              <Detail />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/user">
              <User />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/LoginSignup">
              <LoginSignup />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

With this configuration, I got this error:

```
"It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

CommonJS Modules:
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/<PACKAGE>');

ES Modules:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';

Typescript:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';"
```

And also:

> Uncaught t {code: "auth/invalid-api-key", message: "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.", a: null}

I have tried to add these lines to firebase.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
```

And I have researched on Google and Stackoverflow but couldn't solve it. I am absolutely sure that the API key is correct. I checked it over and over. I think I'm missing something.

This is the screenshot of the error:
[image: Error Screenshot]

On these lines, what am I missing?

Comment: To solve the first problem use `import firebase from "firebase/app";`, as also shown in many search results if you [search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=It+looks+like+you%27re+using+the+development+build+of+the+Firebase+JS+SDK.). I recommend fixing that first, and then removing it from the question, so that people can focus on the second problem.

Answer (score 1):

Swap `import firebase from "firebase";`. with `import firebase from "firebase/app";` to get rid of the development build warning. Make sure you remove the original line or the error won't go away.

To fix the ID try going to `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]/settings/general/`

Over there you should have a properly prefilled firebaseConfig that you can copy paste.